# Why are img and div widths miscalculated in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, html, center

I use following code to center images horizontally and vertically in DIV
Properties given to DIV is `width` & `height`, `overflow:hidden`, and `display:block`.

Problem: `margin-top` and `margin-left` miscalculated only in Chrome, while code is working perfectly in FF and IE

```
$('.centerImage').each(function(i) {
    var divH = $(this).parent().height();
    var divW = $(this).parent().width();
    var orgImgH = $(this).height();
    var orgImgW = $(this).width();
    if (orgImgH > orgImgW) {
        $(this).css('width', divW);
        var imgH = $(this).height();
        var mTop = (divH - imgH) / 2;
        $(this).css("margin-top", (mTop < 0) ? mTop : -mTop); //if margin-top value is less than 0 use as is and greater than 0 multiply by -1
    } else {
        $(this).css('height', divH);
        var imgW = $(this).width();
        var mLeft = (divW - imgW) / 2;
        //alert(imgW); alert(mLeft); //chrome bug
        $(this).css("margin-left", (mLeft < 0) ? mLeft : -mLeft);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is this code being executed within a dom ready callback? i.e. `$(document).ready();` and are you sure all your images have their widths and heights fully loaded by the time this code is executed. Chrome tends to run a little faster than the other browsers so may highlight race conditions more readily. By 'miscalculated' do you mean off by a few pixels or just totally wrong?

Comment: try alert() some of the variables or writing them to some html element. I would also check what is "this" referring to. is the code being called after the document has loaded?

Comment: @Martin - `this` will definitely be referring to each element in turn that has the class 'centerImage' applied.

Comment: Yes code is executed in `$(document).ready();` and I am actually running it in a static local page so yes all images are perfectly loaded. in chrome, it just calculates margin left value and it's always equal -97! even if the case is that the image should be given margin top, it gives it the margin left value equals -97!

Comment: @user63795: Did you ever get this sorted out? If you found a solution please post it and accept your own answer as the answer then. that will help any future user with similar issue to be able to see what worked for you.