# jQuery animate imprecise

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slider

I built slider that makes use of jQuery's animate. The slides should move to the left and to the right.
Sometimes the animation is imprecise by 1 Pixel. Let's say it should slide to 0 Pixels from left but it stops at 1 Pixel. At least in Google Chrome I experience this problem.
Why is that and how can I prevent it?

Here's the function:

```
var faces_width = 414;

function facebox_next (id) {
    var index = parseInt($(id).attr("index"));
    index++;
    if(index <= $(id).children("img").size()-1) {
        $(id).attr("index",index);
        $(id).animate({
            "left":-faces_width*index
        },300);
        //$(id).css("left",-faces_width*index);
    }
}

function facebox_prev (id) {
    var index = parseInt($(id).attr("index"));
    index--;
    if(index >= 0) {
        $(id).attr("index",index);
        $(id).animate({
            "left":-faces_width*index
        },300);
        //$(id).css("left",-faces_width*index);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vXYdu/

Comment: when you say "sometimes", what do you mean? can you discern a pattern?

Comment: It happens when I click forth and back through the slider-items a few times.

Comment: is it consistent (as in always after the same number of times)? I would also suggest creating a JSFiddle so we can take a closer look.

Comment: I made a fiddle. Don't laugh at the pictures ;)
Just click the arrows left and right a few times and you'll see.
You should use Google Chrome because it doesn't seem to happen in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just change the `facechanger` div to 1px smaller width, that solved the problem for me

```
div#facechanger {position:relative; height:542px; margin:32px 0;width:540px}
```

Comment: This only seems to work for the head not for the other 3 elements.

Comment: I didn't even notice it was happening in the face

Comment: there are known bugs with Chrome calculating width settings when there is math involved like yours has because Chrome runs faster then other browsers , I would suggest setting an alert() in a couple of spots to see when value the browser is getting @manticore

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468124/why-are-img-and-div-widths-miscalculated-in-chrome   - no good answer though